# Spring + MyBatis exception: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, mapper

I got this exception when I executed this app:

```
public class MainApp {

    private static ApplicationContext context = null;
    static SqlSession session = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {

            context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                                            "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");
            session = (SqlSession) context.getBean("sqlSession");
            OrderMapper orderMapper = session.getMapper(OrderMapper.class);
            int orderQuantity = orderMapper.getAllOrder().size();
            System.out.println("Order quantity: " + orderQuantity);
            session.commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my OrderMapper interface:

```
public interface OrderMapper {

    public List<Order> getAllOrder();
}
```

OrderMapper.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
 "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.thonglm1.spring.mappers.OrderMapper">

    <resultMap id="result" type="order">
        <result property="orderId" column="cartid" />
        <result property="type" column="type" />
        <result property="saleId" column="saleId" />
        <result property="status" column="status" />
        <result property="info1" column="info1" />
        <result property="info2" column="info2" />
        <result property="info3" column="info3" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllOrder" resultMap="result">
        select cartId, type,
        info1
        from TRAIN_ORDER;
    </select>
</mapper>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.8.62:1521:SHESVDEV" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.thonglm1.spring.mappers" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="com.thonglm1.spring.domain.Order" alias="order" />
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <package name="com.thonglm1.spring.mappers" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

And finally, the exception I got:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does
>   not contain value for
>   com.thonglm1.spring.mappers.OrderMapper.getAllOrder   at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:507)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:500)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.setupCommandType(MapperMethod.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.(MapperMethod.java:71)
>     at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:39)
>     at $Proxy6.getAllOrder(Unknown Source)  at
>   MainApp.main(MainApp.java:21)

And 1 more thing, since I quite new to this, is there any bad practices in my code ? Or anything I could improve ? Please feel free to comment, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Three names have to match - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616498/715269

Answer (score 2):

Where have you specified the mapper XML location? You could add it in sqlSessionFactory's property `mapperLocations`. Since you are using maven. I believe it is better to move the mapper XML file to a folder inside `resources` directory. When You add more number of XML files it will be easier to maintain. I think the below folder structure would make sense as all the related stuff are grouped together with all your JDBC related stuff under one package with subpackages as domain, mappers, service interfaces and service interface implementation.

[image]

In this case since all the configurations go inside WEB-INF/classes directory during compile/packaging, which is also a classpath, this application configuration should hold good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.8.62:1521:SHESVDEV" />
        <property name="username" value="test" />
        <property name="password" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:config/mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.thonglm1.spring.mappers" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And the `mybatis-config.xml`, by default all the aliases in the domain package will be class name with the first letter being smaller.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.thonglm1.spring.domain" />
    </typeAliases>       
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry but I cant see your pic, could you upload it somewhere else and send me the link. Thank you very much!

Comment: And I store the xml mapper file in the same package with the mapper class. I think it should be loaded automatically.

Comment: I don't have any sharing links... I believe you can use different browser which will display the image. If you need xml file in same location as that interface, in that case please check once, if the xml's are copied during compiletime. In maven there are configuartion option which allows you to copy only .class to classes directory. Hence in you case the xml might have been excluded.

Answer (score 0):

If the package cannot be read you can try adding the resource directly:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeAliases>
        <typeAlias type="com.thonglm1.spring.domain.Order" alias="order" />
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="folderWhereIsXMLMapperIssaved/orderMapper.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I tried to use: "<mapper resource="com/thonglm1/spring/mappers/OrderMapper.xml"" instead of using package tag, but it threw another exception: "<mapper resource="com/thonglm1/spring/mappers/OrderMapper.xml"".