# Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mybatis mapper

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring, mybatis

I am user mybatis and spring to create some test website. Right now I got a problem when trying to use mybatis xml mapper. Issue is something like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper.getAdminByUsername"

servlet.xml

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/cooldrinker/mybatis/mapper/*.xml" />
    </bean>
```

Java mapper

```
package com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper;

import com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin;

public interface AdminMapper {
    public Admin getAdminByUsername(String username);
}
```

xml mapper

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper">
    <select id="getAdminByUsername" parameterType="java.lang.String" resultType="adminResultMap">
        SELECT first_name, last_name, password, username
        FROM admin
        WHERE username = #{username}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="adminResultMap" type="com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin">
        <result property="firstName" column="first_name" />
        <result property="username" column="last_name"/>
        <result property="password" column="password"/>
        <result property="username" column="username"/>
    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

stack trace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper.getAdminByUsername
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper.getAdminByUsername
    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:672)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:507)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:500)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.setupCommandType(MapperMethod.java:240)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:71)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:39)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.mybatis.dao.impl.AdminDaoImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminDaoImpl.java:24)
    com.cooldrinker.dataservice.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminServiceImpl.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.controller.AdminLoginController.login(AdminLoginController.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: make sure your xml mapper's name end with "AdminMapper.xml"

Comment: The xml file location does not requires to be in the same path as the interface package. It can be on classpath root or any sub-directory. The most important is _mapper namespace_ must equal _interface full qualified name_ The xml contents seems ok, then the xml file might not be loaded at all. Try referencing explicitly the file in property mapperLocations, the issue might be related to wild-cards

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error was due to wrong reference between DAO ↔ XML

Let me show IMPLEMENTS in "AdminMapper" AND "AdminMapperDAO"
Maybe that was point.

Answer (score 1):

[The three names have to match:](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Mapped-Statements-collection-does-not-contain-value-td2553948.html)

- interface = com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper.class
- mapper file = com/cooldrinker/mybatis/mapper/AdminMapper.xml
- mapper namespace = com.cooldrinker.mybatis.mapper.AdminMapper

If they don't match, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you may register your mapper in `mybatis-config.xml` file

```
<configuration>

  <properties resource="db.dev.properties">
  </properties>

    <typeHandlers>
        <package name="com.newtonx.model.typehandlers"/>
    </typeHandlers>
    <environments default="development">
     ...
    </environments>
    <mappers>
      <mapper resource="com/project/model/xml/SomeMapper.xml"/>
      // other mapper here
    </mappers>
    ...
</configuration>
```