# Spring + Mybatis Sqlsession Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mapping/UserMapper.getUserById

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis

when I'm using juit test Spring Mybatis select user found this one.

- UserMapper.xml namespace is correct
- sqlSessionFactory is right

but can't found issue.

my directory structure is:

[image]

```
    import com.f.dao.UserMapper;
    import com.f.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class TestUserMapper {
        @Test
        public void addUser() {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
            UserMapper userMapper = (UserDaoImpl) context.getBean("userDaoImpl");
            System.out.println(userMapper.getUserById(1));
        }
    }
```

I'm using debugger trace on `sqlSession.selectOne("mapping/UserMapper.getUserById", id);`
catch error:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mapping/UserMapper.getUserById
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mapping/UserMapper.getUserById
```

this is summary config file
`spring-context.xml`

[image]

`Datasource` config seem is right
`UserMapper.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.f.dao.UserMapper">
    <insert id="insertUser" parameterType="User">
        INSERT INTO users(user_name, passwd, email)
        VALUES (#{userName}, #{password}, #{email})
    </insert>

    <resultMap id="getUserByIdUserResult" type="User">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="email" column="email"/>
        <result property="userName" column="user_name"/>
        <result property="password" column="passwd"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="getUserById" parameterType="int" resultMap="getUserByIdUserResult">
        SELECT id, user_name, passwd, email FROM users
        WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

`UserMapper.java`

```
public interface UserMapper {
    public int insertUser(User user);

    public User getUserById(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

Comment: I do not know iBatis but that you declare the email property in the result map and do not select it is wanted?

Comment: oh, seem issue not here, after add email field still report `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mapping/UserMapper.getUserById`

Comment: If you set logging to debug can you see whether the mapping/UserMapper.xml is loaded?

Comment: Your Namespace is com.f.dao.UserMapper, so try to use com.f.dao.UserMapper instead of just UserMapper in statement sqlSession.selectOne("mapping/UserMapper.getUserById", id);

Comment: Three names have to match - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616498/715269