# Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData

Tags: java, xml, mybatis, mapper

There are no problems when running the application but during run-time when the api is being called my error pop-up.

I've already tried other solutions presented by other devs in here in stack overflow but no luck, and the error is still the same.

Here is my code:

FiedlDataDaoImpl.java

```
@Component
public class FieldDataDaoImpl implements FieldDataDao{

    @Autowired
    private SqlSession sqlSession;

    @Override
    public FieldData getFieldData() throws SQLException, Exception {
        FieldData result = new FieldData();

        try {
            result = this.sqlSession.selectOne("getFieldData");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <!-- <package name="com.pnb.allianz.bir.model" /> -->
        <typeAlias alias="FieldData" type="com.pnb.allianz.jdt.model.FieldData"/>
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="xml-mappers/FieldData.xml" />
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

FieldData.xml

```
<mapper>
     <resultMap id="FieldDataResultMap" type="FieldData">
        <result column="LF2S_TRAN_TYPE"         property="transactionType"/>
        <result column="LF2S_DISTRIBUTION"      property="distribution"/>
        <result column="LF2S_REPORT_TYPE"   property="reportType"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getFieldData" resultMap="FieldDataResultMap" >
        SELECT * FROM LF2S_MR_PARAMETERS
        WHERE rownum =1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.transaction.rollback-on-commit-failure=true
#LOCAL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@sddevdb2.myhouse.com:1555:JLDEV
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=1234

#mybatis configuration
mybatis.config=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

GenerateJdtController.java

```
@Controller
public class GenerateJdtController {

    @Autowired
    FieldDataService fieldDataService;

    @RequestMapping("/generate-gdt")
    ModelAndView getView(Model model) throws SQLException, Exception {
        model.addAttribute("wc_msg", fieldDataService.getFieldData());
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

.. and the error goes like this when http://localhost:8080/generate-gdt is called

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:158)
    at com.pnb.allianz.jdt.dao.impl.FieldDataDaoImpl.getFieldData(FieldDataDaoImpl.java:23)
    at com.pnb.allianz.jdt.service.impl.FieldDataServiceImpl.getFieldData(FieldDataServiceImpl.java:20)
    at com.pnb.allianz.jdt.controller.GenerateJdtController.getView(GenerateJdtController.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getFieldData
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration$StrictMap.get(Configuration.java:946)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:739)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.getMappedStatement(Configuration.java:732)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:146)
    ... 76 more
```

I really need this I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Three names have to match - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60616498/715269

Answer (score 0):

Your mapper needs `namespace`.

```xml
<!-- FieldData.xml -->
<mapper namespace="FieldData">
```

```java
// FiedlDataDaoImpl.java
result = this.sqlSession.selectOne("FieldData.getFieldData");
```

Please see the [doc](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#Exploring_Mapped_SQL_Statements) for the details.